# How to excute Raw SQL Query on NestJS framework using typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am going to execute such a long query on the NestJS framework using Typeform.
Please let me know how to execute this query.

```
select user.id, user.fullName, (select count(*) sendCnt from chat where senderId = user.id), (select count(*) recvCnt from chat where receiverId = user.id) from users user where user.role = 'Admin'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using `TypeORM` you can inject the connection using `@InjectConnection()` and use `query` to run a raw query, as shown in the [TypeORM docs](https://typeorm.io)

```js
const rawData = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS`);
```

---

Assuming you're using `@nestjs/typeorm`, `this.connection` can be obtained through the `@InjectConnection()` decorator in the constructor

```js
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private readonly connection: Connection) {}

  async doSomeQuery() {
    return this.connection.query('SELECT * FROM USERS;');
  }
}
```

---

As of Nest v9  (and somewhere in @nestjs/typeorm@8, rather late in the version) TypeORM v0.3.0 is used and `@InjectConnection()` is deprecated. `@InjectDataSource()` should be used instead

Comment: Currently, I am using PostgreSQL.
Could you please let me know the detailed base code for this functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.

Comment: Please, provide a bit more information if you can, i.e: how you import connection and inject it in constructor or? Thanks.

Comment: @textoro just added a small example

Comment: @JayMcDoniel et al. `@InjectConnection()` decorator is now deprecated. Use `@InjectDataSource()` now.

Answer (score 2):

you can use typeorm - DataSource module for execute raw SQL queries

please refer below example

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export class <class name> {
  constructor(
 @InjectDataSource() private dataSource: DataSource,
) {}

  async function_name () {
     this.dataSource.query(<QUERY>)
  }
}
```

Comment: After InjectConnection() is deprecated. This solution work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder to create the required query -

```
return await getRepository(users)
.createQueryBuilder("user")
.where("user.role = 'Admin'")
.select("user.id as userId")
.addSelect("user.fullName as fullName")
.addSelect("(select count(*) sendCnt from chat where senderId = user.id) as sendCnt")
.addSelect("(select count(*) recvCnt from chat where receiverId = user.id) as recvCnt")
.printSql()
.getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';

const entityManager = getManager();
return entityManager.query(`SELECT * FROM users`)
```

On your case:

```
return entityManager.query(`select user.id, user.fullName, (select count(*) sendCnt from chat where senderId = user.id), (select count(*) recvCnt from chat where receiverId = user.id) from users user where user.role = 'Admin'`)
```